# Using ANTLR4 translating from DSL to Java, need strategy for rebuilding (not evaluating) expressions

Tags: java, parsing, design-patterns, compiler-construction, antlr4

I am using ANTLR4 to translate ("compile") from a simple artificial programming language with limited vocabulary to Java. As this exercise does not require any evaluation, and so even conditional expressions will only be translated in full to equivalent Java code, I am working on implementing a listener-based solution. With the limited language vocabulary I have been able to wrap my head around most of the translation tasks and related strategies, relying heavily on a simple single-scope symbol table to hold and compare compile time and runtime variables (remember, no evaluation of expressions is being performed).

Simple arithmetic and comparison expressions are easy enough to parse and convert to Java; however, I have run into trouble with nested and compound expressions. They parse fine, but translating them Java is an issue. I have attempted a number of strategies for handling them, most of which incorporate getting lhs and rhs of an expression and checking using various mechanisms whether one is an embedded expression or not (for example, checking for occurrence of parentheses or other operators within the string representation), checking for variables and looking them up in the symbol table, and if a lhs or rhs is determined to be a number or valid variable it is pushed onto a stack, along with an operator. However, popping these stack elements off and attempting to re-piece the expressions in correct order is futile, since nesting positions of expressions affect when they are pushed and where related operators are placed.

I feel I'm on the right path re: my strategy for storing and re-generating expressions, but need a nudge. However, I fear I may be wasting time if I am *not* on the right path or if there is a better way of doing this, perhaps via a well-tested design pattern.

The full grammar is shown below. I think it's pretty self-explanatory... except maybe the triple quotes (""") used for embedded quotation mark escaping within a string. Remember, it's a very limited language and I am *not* evaluating any expressions.

```
grammar Test;

prog        
    : (stat ';')+
    | COMMENT ;

stat        
    : assign
    | if_stat
    | loop_stat
    | expr
    | get
    | put
    ;

assign      
    : VARIABLE '=' expr
    ;

if_stat     
    : 'if' expr 'then' (stat ';')+ (('elsif' expr 'then' (stat ';')+)* 'else' (stat ';')+)? 'end if'
    ;

loop_stat   
    : 'loop' ('exit when' expr ';')* (stat ';')+ 'end loop'
    ;

expr
    : number                                   #Num
    | variable                                 #Var
    | '!' expr                                 #LogNeg
    | expr '&' expr                            #LogAnd
    | expr '|' expr                            #LogOr
    | expr ('='|'<>'|'<'|'>'|'<='|'>=') expr   #Comp
    | '-' expr                                 #Neg
    | expr ('*'|'/'|'%') expr                  #MultDivRem
    | expr ('+'|'-') expr                      #AddSub
    | '(' expr ')'                             #Parens
    ;

get     
    : 'get' variable (',' variable)*
    ;

put 
    : 'put' (expr|str) (',' (expr|str))*
    ;

number
    : NUMBER
    ;

variable    
    : VARIABLE
    ;

str     
    : STRING
    ;

COMMENT         : '#' .*? '\n'  -> skip ;
WS              : [ \t\n\r]+    -> skip ;

VARIABLE        : LETTER (LETTER|DIGIT|'_')* ;
NUMBER          : DIGIT (DIGIT|'_' DIGIT)* ;
STRING          : ('"""'|'"') .*? ('"""'|'"') ;

fragment LETTER : [a-z] | [A-Z] ;
fragment DIGIT  : [0-9] ;
```

A sample of a expression processing method is as follows:

```
public void enterAddSub(SimpleParser.AddSubContext ctx) {

    // Simplified example does not account for variables.

    boolean opSeen = false;

    // Get operator and left and right hand expressions.
    String op = ctx.getChild(1).getText();
    String lhs = ctx.getChild(0).getText();
    String rhs = ctx.getChild(2).getText();

    // lhs is not a nested expression, print it. If nested, skip for now.
    if (isInteger(lhs) == true) {
        //System.out.print(lhs + " " + op + " ");
        cts.push(lhs);
        cts.push(op);
        opSeen = true;
    }

    // rhs is not a nested expression, print it. If nested, skip for now.
    if (isInteger(rhs) == true) {
        //System.out.print(rhs);
        cts.push(rhs);
    }

    else {
        if (opSeen == false) {
            //System.out.print(op);
            cts.push(op);
        }
    }

    //System.out.println();
}
```

The corresponding expr exit method simply pops everything off the stack into a string, which is then a puzzle not in order that needs to be placed back together, and I cannot come up with an algorithm that consistently places elements where they need to be.

Also, I don't override the Number or Variable methods, and instead use a top-down approach to access these elements from within their enclosing exprs. Perhaps this is causing me a problem; unfortunately, if it is, I can't see how.

Any suggestion on how to continue attacking this problem the same way or how to change strategy would be appreciated.

I have looked at numerous questions and examples on SO but cannot find an equivalent, and have Parr's ANTLR4 reference book, which is very useful, but cannot find a strategy for this particular problem in either spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of handling this is to go ahead and use a scoped symbol table - or more particularly a scoped 'op' table.  Push scope on every 'enterExpr' and pop on every 'exitExpr'.  On the enter of each sub-expr, such as 'enterAddSub', add an 'op object' characterizing the operator of that sub-expr to the current scope.

Now, on enter and exit of every 'expr', evaluate the op object in the parent scope to see if there is some part of the op that you need to print. In the particular case of 'enterAddSub' and choosing a strategy of printing the operator prior to printing anything from the second expr, include a counter in the op object so that on the third evaluation of the op object print the operator (else increment the counter).  For the parens sub-rule, the strategy is on evaluation from an enterExpr print "(" and from an exitExpr print ")".

For simple cases, it is usually sufficient for the op object to have 'onEnter' and 'onExit' methods to invoke self-evaluation and conditionally print a result.

In more interesting cases, particularly when translation can benefit from deferred evaluation, the op object becomes an intelligent accumulator. On each 'onExit' evaluation, it decides whether to print, accumulate, or add its values to the op object in its parent scope.

```
enterExpr:
  pushScope()
  parentScope().onEntry()
    enterAddSub:
      currentScope().add(new OpObject(ADDSUB))  // enum
        enterExpr 
          visit ...
        exitExpr
        enterExpr
          visit ...
        exitExpr
    exitAddSub:
      currentScope().finalize()
exitExpr:
  call parentScope().onExit()
  popScope()
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. As I look at your answer, I'm wondering if the 'visit' is referring to using a visitor, or a more general idea of visiting the expression as encountering them. I am using listeners, which should suffice, right?

Comment: By visit I was just indicating that there was further depth to the tree walk.  Both listeners and visitor provide 'on entry' and 'on exit' calls. Visitors, however, return a value object that can make passing data around a bit easier. Other than that, there is no real difference between visitors and listeners. Boils down to whatever feels right to you for your particular project.